# Filter df based on multiple different values for multiple different groups

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

Example data:

```
set.seed(99999)
library(dplyr)

Group <- c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4),rep("C",4))
Value <- abs(rnorm(12))
df <- data.frame(Group,Value)
df$Group <- as.character(df$Group)
```

I would like to filter each group, i.e. A,B,C, based on a different value in the column "Value". In dplyr it would look like this:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  filter(Group=="A" & Value>=0.2 |
         Group=="B" & Value>=0.1 |
         Group=="C" & Value>=0.6)
```

However, my real df is much larger with >100 groups and each one has a unique threshold value to filter by. Therefore I have a seperate df3, which only has the thresholds per group:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Group=c("A","B","C"),Value=c(0.2,0.1,0.6))
```

How could I filter the df with the respective threshold values in df3 per corresponding group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution uses `group_by(Group)` and `inner_join()` to merge the threshold values by group, and then uses `filter()` to retain rows where `Value` exceeds `threshold`.

```
set.seed(99999)
library(dplyr)

Group <- c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4),rep("C",4))
Value <- abs(rnorm(12))
df <- data.frame(Group,Value,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$Group <- as.character(df$Group)
df3 <- data.frame(Group=c("A","B","C"),threshold=c(0.2,0.1,0.6),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% group_by(Group) %>%
   inner_join(df3) %>% filter(Value > threshold)
```

Note that I changed the column name in `df3` from `Value` to `threshold` to avoid a column name conflict in `inner_join()`.

...and the output:

```
Joining, by = "Group"
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   Group [3]
  Group Value threshold
  <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A     0.426       0.2
2 A     0.283       0.2
3 A     0.899       0.2
4 A     0.707       0.2
5 B     2.09        0.1
6 B     1.64        0.1
7 B     0.540       0.1
8 B     0.604       0.1
9 C     0.956       0.6
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the old split - apply - combine method:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  split(df$Group) %>%
  lapply(filter, Value > df3$Value[df3$Group == Group[1]]) %>%
  bind_rows()
#>   Group     Value
#> 1     A 0.4255127
#> 2     A 0.2829203
#> 3     A 0.8986773
#> 4     A 0.7065184
#> 5     B 2.0916699
#> 6     B 1.6356643
#> 7     B 0.5401934
#> 8     B 0.6037287
#> 9     C 0.9558980
```